# Write cookie in ashx file

Tags: javascript, asp.net, cookies

i try write new cookie in ashx file,but i get error

```
 HttpCookie cookname;
        for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
        {
            HttpPostedFile file = files[i];

            string filename = "~/img/" + "111" + file.FileName;
            filenames.Add(filename);
            file.SaveAs(context.Server.MapPath(filename));
            cookname["filename"] = filename;
            Response.Cookies.Add(cookname);

        }
```

And how i can get cookie in javascript?
Thank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to initialize **HttpCookie** first with a name like

```
HttpCookie cookName = new HttpCookie("yourCookieName");
```

Then add value whatever you want like

```
cookName["yourPropertyName"] = value;
```

To get cookie in javascript, you can use following function

```
function getCookie(cname) {
   var name = cname + "=";
   var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
   for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
      var c = ca[i];
      while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
      if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
   }
    return "";
}
```

Then call the function to get cookie like

```
getCookie("yourCookieName=yourPropertyName")
```